# Return indexes in list until there are none left

Tags: python, list, split

I'm trying to iterate through strings in a list that are inconsistent and only return however many strings are present (along with spaces in between). The field below is what I have:

```
119|N|Thompson|Compl.  
120|N|Thompson|InCompl.
121|W|        |
```

And my expected output is that I'm trying to get is:

```
N Thompson Compl.
N Thompson Incompl.
W
```

I initially tried a pretty basic function:

```
def Split(field):
    x = field.split("|")
    return x[1] + " " + x[2] + " " + x[3]
```

But since my data is inconsistent and does not always have indexes `2` and `3`, it obviously won't work. I tried enumerating the list but I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
def Split(field):
    x = field.split("|")
    for idx, val in enumerate(x):
        #do stuff
```

I'd just like to return however many indexes there are (except for index `0` which will always be a number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `join` to get a string for any list:

```
def Split(field):
    return ' '.join(field.split("|")[1:])
```

If there is not even a single field you would need to `try` and `except` it:

```
def Split(field):
    try: return ' '.join(field.split("|")[1:])
    except IndexError: return '' #Empty string if there is no index 1
```